# Safe way to remove '/public' from URL in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, url

I am using laravel and in a problem with the **'/public'** included in URL. I have searched on the internet to remove it. Some links suggested to edit htaccess file but found it risky as it will allow env and other files to open access. 
Anybody suggest me to remove /public from url in a safe way.

Note: I am using Apache shared server hosting.

Comment: What you mean by `/public` in URL? Did you create a route with public name?

Comment: It shouldn't include `/public` in the URL at all. The web root should be the public folder

Comment: Configure your server correctly. Set the document root to the `public` folder, as recommended by the Laravel documentation.

Comment: On which file i have to make change to set document root ? guide me, i am new to this.

Comment: Apache or Nginx? What Operating system?

Comment: Apache, using shared server

Comment: I updated my document root from my shared hosting control panel and solved the issue, thank you, everyone, for the response, Proper detail is added as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer, 
To remove '/public' from laravel default url (ie: 'www.yoursite.com/public') on shared hosting similar to my situation, 
Just add '/public' at the end of my site location in document root.

Example Image:
 [image: if you have following document root in your shared hosting then just replace in with '/public_html/newdomain.com/public']

Note: if you have following document root in your shared hosting then just replace in with '/public_html/newdomain.com/public'